# how use findAll() method in sequelize to get table data from postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have used postgres for database and sequelize for ORM in nodejs, but when I tried to get all data from table using findAll() method in sequelize it gets undefined, and select query executes but at the place of data it shows undefined, tell me what i do wrong here?

```
const Data=require('./Data') 
var Sequelize=require('sequelize')
const connection = new Sequelize('mydb', 'postgres', '12345', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect:  'postgres' 
  });
  var Emp=connection.define('emp',{
    fullName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
})
  connection.sync().then(function(){
      Emp.findAll().then(function(emps){
          console.log(emps.dataValues)
      })
  })
```

**output**

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "emps" ("id"   SERIAL , "fullName" VARCHAR(255), "email" VARCHAR(255), "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'emps' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "fullName", "email", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "emps" AS "emp";
undefined
```

Comment: please format the output part of your question.

Comment: ok now formating the output part plz tell me what i did here wrong

Comment: You created a new table `emps`. There is no data record in the table.

Comment: i have created table, and i insert data into table from same program, after that i removed insert code and put there SELECT code thats it, and if i open database there is data inserted successfully

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my problem , just i did simple mistake and i solved it now and data is fetched from database table by using findAll() function in sequelize...

```
**code before changes:**

    connection.sync().then(function(){
          Emp.findAll().then(function(emps){
              console.log(emps.dataValues) //line with mistake
          })
      })
```

```
**code after changes:**

    connection.sync().then(function(){
                Emp.findAll().then(function(emps){
                              console.log(emps) //here i did changes
                  })
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the code with the information you have provided with. 
But it seems everything is working properly on my side here. 
I do not know if you have set sequelize configuration options database, or how you have structure and organized the project itself. 
Maybe this would help: [instantiate sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor), plese look under for "*Instantiate sequelize with name of database, username and password.*", the params and attributes will help to get an idea of it.

Anyways, I also took the liberty to make an basic code on the information you have shared us with: [sequelize how use findall()](https://gitlab.com/sistemaon/stackoverflow-eqa/-/tree/master/how-user-findall-method-sequelize-get-table-data-postgresql).

Hope these can help you to go thru with it. Have a great one!

Comment: You created Api with my same code thats great but i cannot connect file with api yet, and i have configured well because table is created in database when i execute the code

Comment: If is this line you are talking about it const Data=require('./Data'), I unfortunately do not know what it does, where is it using it and what does contain, that is the reason I left out of it. I see you require it, but I do not see you using it.